# Hybris : Failed to lookup BaseSite for BusinessProcess [AbcCartEmailProcessModel (87976318374)]. Unable to setup session context

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to trigger email in hyrbis. For that i have written some code in respective context file.

```
public class AbcCartEmailContext extends AbstractEmailContext<AbcCartEmailProcessModel>
{


private final String myEmail = "tt@gmail.com";
private final String fromEmail = "yy@abc.com";


@Override
public void init(final AbcCartEmailProcessModel businessProcessModel, final EmailPageModel emailPageModel)`{
    put(FROM_EMAIL, fromEmail);
    put(EMAIL, myEmail);
}
@Override
protected BaseSiteModel getSite(final AbcCartEmailProcessModel businessProcessModel)
{
    // YTODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ((StoreFrontProcessModel) businessProcessModel).getSite();
}


@Override
protected CustomerModel getCustomer(final AbcCartEmailProcessModel businessProcessModel)
{
    return ((StoreFrontCustomerProcessModel) businessProcessModel).getCustomer();
}

    @Override
protected LanguageModel getEmailLanguage(final AbcCartEmailProcessModel businessProcessModel)
{
    // YTODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ((StoreFrontCustomerProcessModel) businessProcessModel).getLanguage();
}
}
```

Now when I try to kickoff mail with following lines of code in a method:

```
final AbcCartEmailProcessModel abcCartEmailProcess = (AbcCartEmailProcessModel) this.businessProcessService
            .createProcess("abcCartEmailProcess" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "abcCartEmailProcess");
    abcCartEmailProcess.setSite(baseSiteService.getCurrentBaseSite());
    abcCartEmailProcess.setLanguage(xyzService.getLanguage(MyConstants.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE));
    modelService.save(abcCartEmailProcess);
this.businessProcessService.startProcess(abcCartEmailProcess);
```

I am getting following error:

```
ERROR [TaskExecutor-master-151-ProcessTask [879943539192]] [DefaultProcessContextResolutionStrategy] Failed to lookup BaseSite for BusinessProcess [AbcCartEmailProcessModel (8797633183742)]. Unable to setup session context.
ERROR [TaskExecutor-master-151-ProcessTask [879943539192]] [DefaultProcessContextResolutionStrategy] Failed to lookup BaseSite for BusinessProcess [AbcCartEmailProcessModel (8797633183742)]. Unable to get content catalog.
```

What needs to be done to get rid of this error or to trigger email.

Comment: This is because the BusinessProcess is running in a none web context so it's not aware of the Session neither the Catalog.

Comment: Can you share with us how do you inflate (site, customer, language) into your businessProcessModel ?

Comment: @MouadELFakir I have updated my question with lines of code I am trying to trigger mail. Can you suggest where  am I missing

Comment: As @MouadELFakir said you need a context to call `baseSiteService.getCurrentBaseSite()` I guess if you debug you'll see that it's null. To get rid of that you can save the basesite in an object that you can refer without context, the customer for example.

Comment: i agree with @alain.janinm.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DefaultBaseSiteService extends AbstractBusinessService implements BaseSiteService {

    //...

    protected BaseSiteModel getCurrentBaseSiteImpl() {
        //...

        return (BaseSiteModel)this.getSessionService().getAttribute("currentSite");

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

As you can see the default implementation of `baseSiteService.getCurrentBaseSite()` retrieves currentSite from the session (which you don't own at this level) .

I propose if you have only one baseSite (as most of the time) to retrieve it using a simple flexible search `SELECT {pk} FROM {BaseSite} WHERE {uid} = 'your_unique_id'` or try @alain.janinm proposition it should work in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mouad. Actually I Was triggering this email through backend job(Cron job) which was running outside hybris web session. That's why I was getting null through getCurrentBaseSite() method.